# How can I split the numeric data into group of 500 each, without sorting the data in R?

Tags: r, split

This question might look simple but I am not able to find the correct function to get desired output.

I extracted the required data from uploaded text file using following code in R -

```
> library(stringr)
> library(readr)
> 
> myFile = readLines(file.choose())
> 
> myResult = list() 
> 
> vars = c(which(str_detect(myFile, "^\\[.*\\]\\s*$") == T), length(myFile))
> 
> for(i in 1:(length(vars)-1)){
+   myData = myFile[vars[i]:(vars[i+1]-1)]
+ #remove lines that are comments or blank
+ myData = myData[!str_detect(myData, "^\\s*#|^\\s*$")]
+ 
+ #if content is a list of variables, create them as a list
+ if(str_detect(myData[2],"=")){
+   content = str_split(myData[-1],"=")
+   result = lapply(lapply(content,"[",2), parse_guess)
+   names(result) = sapply(content,"[",1)
+ } else{
+   #if the content just a vector of data, extract it
+   result = parse_guess(myData[-1])
+ }
+ #create the variable as a list item and assign the content 
+ myResult[[str_remove_all(myData[1], "\\[\\]")]]=result
+ }
> 
> 
> myFile = myResult$`[specdata0]`
> 
> myFile=myFile[1:(myResult$`[specchannel0]`$fRPMmean*4/myResult$`[specchannel0]`$dF)]
> 
> View(myFile)
>
```

myFile has data in following way - image [myFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muGfc.png)

I want to divide this data into groups of 500.

How can I do this?

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Do you want centiles but 500 instead of 100? I'm not sure what the word for that is. Quincentile?

Comment: @Edward How can I get centiles ?

Comment: `quantile` function with `probs=seq(0, 1, 0.01)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want centiles, or any other quantile, then the `cut` function with the breaks set to use quantiles should work.

```
tile <- 100  # percentile. tile <- 5 gives quintiles
myFile$Q500 <- cut(myFile$V1, breaks=quantile(myFile$V1, probs = seq(0,1,1/tile), include=TRUE))

> head(myFile)
                 V1                  Q500
    1 -7.183715e-04 (-0.000736,-0.000698]
    2  8.321956e-04    (0.000816,0.00085]
    3  1.056979e-03      (0.00105,0.0011]
    4  7.017239e-04   (0.000679,0.000723]
    5  2.547699e-03     (0.00237,0.00407]
    6  7.163038e-06  (-1.28e-05,9.48e-06]
___
```

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
myFile <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(4031, 0, 0.001))
```